# Change value of two input fields to the same value, regardless of which field is used

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two fields on my product's page, using the class '.qty'. What I want to achieve is that when I enter a value in either of the input fields, both of these input fields are filled with that value.

My current code is this:

```
function updateProductAmount() {
    jQuery('.add-to-cart .qty').each(function() {
        var productAmount = this.value;
        jQuery('.add-to-cart .qty').val(productAmount);
        // Requires more work.
    });
}
```

I'm calling this code with an `onchange` inside the input text elements.

This code, however only works one way. When the first input element is changed, it copies the value to the last input element. However, when the last input element is changed, it changes back to the value of the first input element.

Can anyone point out to me what I'm doing wrong and help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some working answers below, but just so you know where you went wrong: You're looping through each `.add-to-cart .qty` starting with the *first* one. You then set the value for *all* of the textboxes to that value. Meaning, after the first one, all of your textboxes are set to the same value as the first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 $(document).on('change','.add-to-cart .qty', function(){
    $('.add-to-cart .qty').val($(this).val());
 });
```

[Js Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mj91mb3t/)

Comment: This, potentially, changes more elements than the OP desired.  The selector was `.add-to-cart .qty`, not just all `.qty`.

Comment: Thank you. However, as Makyen states, this will change the other 7 fields on the page that only carry the qty-class. I've tried adjusting your code, using '.add-to-cart. qty', but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I did, however, have to change all the $ to jQuery. But now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the used inputfield as parameter.
ex:
    
to check which field was used.
You could also pass a reference to 2nd field (if it is intended that you stick to two fields. Something along the lines should do the trick

```
<input type="text" value="" name="qty" class="qty" onchange="updateProductAmount(this, jQuery('.add-to-cart'))"/>
<input type="text" value="" name="add-to-cart" class="add-to-cart" onchange="updateProductAmount(this, jQuery('.qty'))"/>
```

and on the script-part

```
function updateProductAmount(caller, fieldToChange) {
    jQuery(fieldToChange).val(caller.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you need change value of **siblings**

```
jQuery( '.add-to-cart .qty' ).on( 'change' , function () {
    jQuery( this ).siblings().val( jQuery( this ).val() );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".qty").on("input",function(){

        $(".qty").not($(this)).val($(this).val());

    })
})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="qty" value="" />
     <input type="text" class="qty" value="" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".qty").on("input",function(){

            $(".qty").not($(this)).val($(this).val());

        })
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` within  jQuery's [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) is the value of the object for this iteration of `each()`, not the element on which the event was fired. You need to store the value to which you are changing the input prior to entering the `each()`.

You then use a second jQuery statement with the `each()` with the same selector to change the value.  This causes all values to be first changed to the first `<input>`'s value, then changed to the second `<input>`'s value, then to the third, etc. However, by the time you get to changing all `<input>` values to the second `<input>`'s value, the second `<input>`'s value has already been changed to the value of the first `<input>`. Effectively, this results in all `<input>`s following the value of the first `<input>` without being able to change any input other than the first.

**Example showing value of `this` within `each()`:**

```js
$('.add-to-cart input.qty').on('input', updateProductAmount);

function updateProductAmount() {
    $('.add-to-cart input.qty').each(function() {
        console.log('This points to id: ' + this.id + " ::value=" + this.value);
        var productAmount = this.value;
        $('.add-to-cart .qty').val(productAmount);
        // Requires more work.
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add-to-cart">
    <input class="qty" id="firstInput">
    <input class="qty" id="secondInput">
</div>
```

**Minimally changed, functional: store `productAmount` before the `each()`:**

```js
$('.add-to-cart input.qty').on('input', updateProductAmount);

function updateProductAmount() {
    var productAmount = this.value;
    $('.add-to-cart input.qty').each(function() {
        $('.add-to-cart .qty').val(productAmount);
        // Requires more work.
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add-to-cart">
    <input class="qty" id="firstInput">
    <input class="qty" id="secondInput">
</div>
```

**In addition:**

- There is no need to change the value for the element on which the event is being fired.  Thus, you can use [`.not($(this))`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to remove it from the jQuery object over which you are iterating with `each()`.
- You, potentially, are iterating over elements that are not `<input>`s.  You can change your selector to only select `<input>` elements.
- Having removed the `var productAmount = this.value;` from within your `each()` it is no longer necessary to explicitly iterate over the jQuery object using `each()`. You can use jQuery's implicit iteration to change the `value` using [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

```js
$('.add-to-cart input.qty').on('input', updateProductAmount);

function updateProductAmount() {
    var productAmount = this.value;
    $('.add-to-cart input.qty').not($(this)).val(productAmount);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add-to-cart">
    <input class="qty" id="firstInput">
    <input class="qty" id="secondInput">
</div>
```

- Now that you are not using `each()`, `this` will refer to the element on which the event is fired.  Thus, there is no need to first store the value in a separate variable. However, if you are expecting to iterate over a *large* number of elements, then using a separate variable will be slightly faster than getting the `value` from the element in each iteration.

**Final code:**

```js
$('.add-to-cart input.qty').on('input', updateProductAmount);

function updateProductAmount() {
    $('.add-to-cart input.qty').not($(this)).val(this.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add-to-cart">
    <input class="qty" id="firstInput">
    <input class="qty" id="secondInput">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. Although I couldn't get the final code to work, your explanation taught me a lot!

Comment: @DaanvandenBergh, I'm glad I was able to help. Do you mean the final code in your usage, or the final snippet within this answer? If you mean the final snippet in this answer: It is working when I test it in Chrome, Firefox and IE11. In what browser/OS/environment are you testing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JS fiddle of what you are trying to do.

```
  function updateProductAmount() {
      $('.qty').val($(this).val());
  }

  $(".qty").change(updateProductAmount);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmedhawas7/zx3sqxft/

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are setting each value for *each input*.  If you trace the code you'll see something like this:

1. Change the first input
2. updateProductAmount is invoked
3. .each is called so we run your function for all elements matching the '.add-to-cart .qty' selector (both inputs)
4. We save off the value of "this" input, which will be the first input found by .each, or the input we actually changed
5. Then the code "jQuery('.add-to-cart .qty').val(productAmount);" will set the value of "productAmount" to all elements that match the '.add-to-cart .qty' selector, which is both inputs.  This means that input 2 now has the value of input 1, like we wanted.
6. Our .each now moves to the second element in the list, retrieves the value of that second input which is equal to the value of the first element by step 5, and sets the value of both inputs to that (which doesn't actually change anything since they both have this value already).

Now, as you can see, if the second input is changed the same order of operations occurs.  This means that the first input will be examined first, and its value will be given to all inputs matching the selector, overwriting the value of the second input with the first.  Therefore, it doesn't matter what the value of the second input is because by the time the .each gets there it has already been overwritten with the value from input 1.

As others have said, the solution here is to simply find all matching elements you would like to update with jQuery and set them to this.value.  Using the [jQuery val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function updates the value of all matched elements, eliminating the need for a .each loop:

```
function updateProductAmount() {
  $('.add-to-cart .qty').val(this.value);
}
```